# In Trigger If exists statement not working and current user and date failed to insert In Postgresql Help me out

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

The below code is executing only else part. Please let me know what mistake I have done.
Even inserting current user and current date not working.

```sql
create or replace function sp_city_dt_trg() returns trigger as $$
begin
    if exists (select 1 from country_master where country_name = new.country_name) then
        if (tg_op = 'INSERT') then
            insert into city(crt_usr_id, crt_date) values(current_user, current_date);
        elsif (tg_op = 'UPDATE') then
            new.upt_usr_id := current_user;
            new.upt_date := current_date;
            insert into city_history values (new.city_name, new.state_name, new.country_name, current_date);
        elseif (tg_op = 'DELETE') then
            insert into city_deleted select * from city where city_id = new.city_id;
        end if;
    else
        raise notice 'No such country';
    end if;
    return null;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

create or replace trigger trg_city
after insert or update or delete on city
for each row
execute function sp_city_dt_trg()
```

I tried commenting that line and execute the rest but even current user and date not entering.

Comment: Possible [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) here: instead of describing your actual goal, you ask us to solve the issue with your attempted solution. I suggest you focus on the former, your trigger only being what you attempted to achieve it. BTW, the `INSERT` part of your trigger looks like if you insert something in `city`, it will trigger an insert into `city`, which will trigger an insert into `city` and so on. Also, after you delete a record, there is nothing left to select from `city` (+ it would need to use `old.city_id`).

Comment: I was trying to auto populate current user and current date while inserting and also while updating. I wanted to check if particular record present or not while doing dml

Comment: I don't understand why you do this to check if a country exists. Would it not be easier to define `city.country_name` with `NOT NULL REFERENCES country_master(country_name)`? That would guarantee it is always filled (leaving `NULL` always raises the `No such country` notice) and equal to an existing country (via foreign key check). Same for setting `current_user` and `current_date`: your rationale not to set them with `DEFAULT` values for the columns definition is ...? All of that points to changing your schema. Besides, edit the question to provide the missing information, not comments.

Comment: Lastly, if your answer to everything I wrote in my previous comment won't work for your use case, you are at least expected to provide a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), i.e. the definition of your tables, sample data and the query that fails to behave like you expect.

Comment: I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the data being inserted/updated you must define the trigger to execute `before` the action (not `after` it):

```sql
create or replace trigger trg_city
before insert or update or delete on city
for each row
execute function sp_city_dt_trg()
```

Also, this looks off:

```
insert into city(crt_usr_id, crt_date) values(current_user, current_date); -- ??
```

Try this instead:

```
new.upt_usr_id := current_user;
new.upt_date := current_date;
```

Comment: It still does not work.